# Surrounding multiple selected lines with #ifdef

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a macro that will allow me to surround currently highlighted lines of text with an #ifdef. Ideally with the cursor placed after the #ifdef to be ready to enter the macro name. I'm able to record to create a macro, but I'm only able to do it for one line of code.

Before:

```
    bool first_selected_line = false;
    int second_selected_line = 0;
```

After:

```
#ifdef // if possible, cursor placed here in insert mode
    bool first_selected_line = false;
    int second_selected_line = 0;
#else
    bool first_selected_line = false;
    int second_selected_line = 0;
#endif
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
qjc#ifdef<esc>magpO#else<esc>gpO#endif<esc>`aq
```

Basically:

- Start recording `qj`
- Delete what you selected and go into insertmode `c`
- Type your construct, pasting your code back as necessary
- You put a mark (`ma`) just after typing #ifdef and jump back to it at the end
- Repeat the macro with `@j`

Hope this example helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use snipmate or some other plugin to accomplish this task. There are couple ways to go about it manually though. Here's my solution for a macro:

Visually select the text then...

```
qqc#ifdef 
<C-r><C-o>"
#else
<C-r><C-o>"
#endif<esc>'[A<C-o>q
```

You also don't have to visually select the text at all if you don't want to. Use the same macro but start with `qqcj` instead.